# Using Eloquent without Laravel - Unable to use DB::

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I am trying to share Eloquent models between a Laravel application and a script that will run as a cron job.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$Capsule = new Capsule;
$Capsule->addConnection(...);
$Capsule->setAsGlobal();
$Capsule->bootEloquent();

// Application logic below...
```

Using the code above, I'm able to work with models as long as they do not make reference to `DB::`. For example, given this class:

```php
namespace MyApp\Modules\Locations\Models;

use DB;
use MyApp\Models\Organisation as BaseOrganisation;

class Organisation extends BaseOrganisation
{
    /**
     * The sites associated with this organisation.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function sites() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Site::class,
            DB::connection('default')->getDatabaseName() . '.global_lu_sites_organisation',
            'organisation_id',
            'site_id'
        );
    }
}
```

This model works in Laravel, but calling `sites()` from the script results in this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DB' not found in .../app/Modules/Locations/Models/Organisation.php on line 14

If I change `use DB;` in the model with `use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;`, then it works at the script level, but not in Laravel.

How can I make use of `DB::` in both Laravel and in a script?

Comment: So to clarify a you want to relate models that are on different databases?

Comment: I don't think it is possibile without bootstraping the whole laravel instance, because `DB` is a facade managed by laravel at runtime

Comment: @hdifen, yes, this already works.

Comment: @gbalduzzi, how would I do something like that?

Comment: You can either add support for facades in your app, or you will have to create a class named `DB` in the global space. In that class you can then extend `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager`.

Comment: Why not just add the CLI code to the Laravel application? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per KFoobar's comment, adding `class DB extends Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager {}` in the global namespace fixed the problem. I think this works because the Capsule Manager relies heavily on static classes.

Answer (score 0):

replace `use DB;` with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Comment: This gives me `RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.`

Comment: How about `\Illuminate\Database\Connection`